# Trouble with multiple age counters (timers)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page where I want to have "age counters" for bids put in by users. The number of users will vary from situation to situation, so that needs to be taken into consideration. I wrote this:

```
function timer(i) {
          // this selects a 'hh:mm:ss' timestamp
        if ($("#time_0" + i).text() !== "") {
            var now = new Date();
            var date = now.toDateString();
            var tStamp = new Date(date + "," + $("#time_0" + i).text());
            var diff = now - tStamp;
            var mins = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60));
            var secs = Math.floor((diff / 1000) % 60);
            if (mins < 10) {
                mins = "0" + mins;
            }
            if (secs < 10) {
                secs = "0" + secs;
            } else if (secs == 60) {
                secs = "00";
            }
            $("#user" + i + "-t").text(mins + ':' + secs);
        }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
                    //
            var ids = [];
            $("td[id^='time_0']").each(function() {
                var i = ($(this).attr("id")).slice(-1);
                ids.push(i);
            });
            for (i in ids) {  // in my example ids = [1,2,3]
                setInterval(function() {timer(i);}, 1000);
            }
});
```

The timer itself functions just as I want it to, but only for user #2 (the middle one). I thought that if I encountered this problem, it would be either the first or last user in the list that had a working timer, but I'm getting blank cells for users #1 and #3.

Does anyone have any ideas as to how I can fix this? Thank you for your time.

==Edit==

I made a bare-bones [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UQZTt/2/)

Comment: would be helpful if you added your code to http://jsfiddle.net/ including the html elements the code is acting on

Comment: @CrayonViolent Sure, I've added it to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your version loop never went past first reference, which was `timer(0)`, because you called your function with `timer(i)`, which was calling the first key in the array `ids`. When you have `setInterval` in a loop it will keep looping the first `setInterval` until that is terminated. By putting that `i` in an anonymous function, each `setInterval` gets fired.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var ids = [];
    $("td[id^='time_0']").each(function () {
        var i = $(this).attr("id").slice(-1);
        ids.push(i);
    });

    for (i in ids) {
        (function(i) { // i needs to be stored into a anonymous function otherwise it gets overwritten
            setInterval(function() {
                timer(ids[i]); // calling just timer(i) would use array keys, not the actual values - ids[i] means: "give me the value of the key of i"
            }, 1000)
        })(i);
    }
});
```

[Made changes to your Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UQZTt/3/)

Comment: It works :D Thank you Damiqib, for solving my problem and teaching me something new about js.